# JavaScript: Get updates from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, client

Is there a way to get constant AJAX updates from the server, other than querying it constantly with `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not really. The server can send data as much as it likes, but the client has to read that, and that has to be checked contantly. You could embed seperate pages that would do the checking for you, but you can't get a request to trigger the check.

Comment: I see. BTW how can the server send the client anything? It doesn't sustain a connection with the client, so it doesn't "know" about the client. Am I wrong?

Comment: By itself, it can, in two ways: one, the server takes note of the client's ip or some other indentification beforehand, and two, the client sends a request to the server first.

Comment: So over Http, can a server send data to clients (without them asking for it directly beforehand)? Is it inside the boundaries of Http?

Comment: Yes, you would have to take note of the client's IP or some other identification using PHP and store it in a MSQL database, and then once that is done send it data. However, as mentioned before, code is not capable of detecting data if it is not checking for it, so your code would have to use a while loop to check for it. That is how I would do it, but you still cant avoid the original problem I'm afraid.